# How to rectify the undocumented error in report viewer?

Tags: asp.net

In rdlc file while i'm trying to add the dataset its show the popup message "Undocumented error".In details its showing that "Prefix '' cannot be mapped to namespace name reserved for "xml" or "xmlns". Line 1, position 87". Can any one help on this.Im new to reports.

Comment: can you show us your dataset how your're trying it?

Comment: Hey after adding the rdlc file ,go to report data in view in that dataset will come.There i'm trying to add the dataset by right click.